# Akka persistence creates new DB connection pool

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

I have akka microservice, for DB I use config like:

```
companyname.db {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  db {
    driver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:1234"
    user = "root"
    password = "password"
    password = ${?DB_PASSWORD}
    connectionPool = "HikariCP"
    numThreads = 20
    minConnections = 10
    maxConnections = 20
    connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"
    idleTimeout = 0
    maxLifetime = 595000
    keepAliveConnection = true
  }
}
```

I have also standard, simple journal config:

```
akka {
  persistence {
    journal {
      plugin = "jdbc-journal"
    }
    snapshot-store {
      plugin = "jdbc-snapshot-store"
    }
  }
}

jdbc-journal = {
  slick = ${abaro.opt.db}
  bufferSize = 5000
}

jdbc-snapshot-store = {
  slick = ${abaro.opt.db}
}

jdbc-read-journal = {
  slick = ${abaro.opt.db}
}
```

and from logs, also by checking VisualVM and by quering `information_schema.processlist` I see that 2 connection pools are created.
I want to change journal to use this main db pool from config, that other code is using.
Is it possible ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sharing a single connection pool is covered with an example config in the akka-persistence-jdbc docs here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-persistence-jdbc/current/configuration.html#sharing-the-database-connection-pool-between-the-journals

Comment: and instead of using my db config as I do now I should use it in shared-databases ?

Comment: just tried it and still 2 pools are created

Comment: Yes, `used-shared-db` in each of your used journal types, with the name of a db pool block defined under `akka-persistence-jdbc.shared-databases`.